# Why does Visual Studio prompt me NOT to use the `this` keyword for instance variables?

Tags: c#, this

With a class as defined below, I would expect that I would need to explicitly state instance variables by prefixing them with 'this'. Coming from a Ruby and Javascript background, I was expecting that `description` would need to be prefixed with `this` at the declaration, and that within the constructor, that `this` would be required.

Why is it not required? I assume that `description` is still getting created as an instance variable?

```
public class Item
{
    private string description;
    public Item(string str)
    {
        this.description = str; // VS says the 'this' keyword can be omitted
    }
}
```

Comment: Because there is no conflicting locally scoped `description` variable and in that case the type or instance member is used.

Comment: It's all 'bout that scope, 'bout that scope, no conflict...

Comment: Because it will aware you with warning if you accidently decide to call your local variable with same name.

Comment: You're executing code in the class scope, so any function or variable is directly accessible, so there's no need for the "this" keyword.

Comment: C# doesn't need it.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not using resharper. Just VS 2015 community

Comment: *Can* be omitted doesn't mean *should* be omitted.

Comment: @ZachSmith you can control this in the VS settings if it bothers you

Comment: In javascript you need to use this in construcotr because you don't need any keyword to declare a variable but in c# you can't do that so you need to use this only if you have declared a variable with the same name inside the constructor or as a constructor parameter

Comment: Be sure to install the Updates, VS2015 is now up to Update 3.  There was a nag in the original RTM release that was turned off in Update 1.  Open the References node of the project, right-click Analyzers, select Open Active Rule Set.  It is IDE0003, iirc the update changed its setting to "Hidden".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is no conflicting locally scoped description variable and in that case the type or instance member is used.

Priority order

1. Local variable
2. Instance member
3. Type (static) member

So if you had a local variable also named `description` but you wanted to reference the instance member then `this` would be required otherwise you would always reference the the local variable.

Here is an example where you should use `this`

```
public class Item
{
    private string description;
    public void SetDescription(string description)
    {
        this.description = description; // without this you would just be setting the local variable to itself
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're asking two different questions.

The first one is, why don't you need `this`.

The reason for that is that C# is a statically typed language. In javascript, you can say `foo = 7`, and a variable `foo` will start to exist.

In C#, you can't do that. `description` refers to `this.description`, and in this context can't refer to anything else.

Your second question is why does Visual Studio tell you not to do that. The answer to that is that notifying you is its default code style.

You can change this behaviour in your editor settings. You can choose what you want your codestyle to be (prefer `this`, prefer not `this`, and either inform or warn when you do something else).

There is nothing inherently wrong in preferring one style over the other, but it's a good idea to be consistent. Visual Studio provides you the tools to be consistent in the style you choose.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely not required, but it is correct so in the end is up to you if you want to use it or not.

I use it mainly because it's an indication that whatever property or method it's used it, I know it's inside that class so there is no ambiguity. Both VS and Resharper will pick up on that but I would say it's a personal preference whether you want to use it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some excerpts from the [C# Language Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), which is the authorative source for how C# works (emphasis added):

> §3.7: The scope of a member declared by a class-member-declaration (§10.1.6) is the **class-body in which the declaration occurs**.

That means you can access the `Item.description` field by its name from all instance methods of `Item`. Because the variable is in scope, you don't need `this`.

> §3.7: The scope of a local variable declared in a local-variable-declaration (§8.5.1) is the **block in which the declaration occurs**.

That means you *could* access a local variable `description` within the block it's defined in.

> §3.7.1.1 Name hiding through nesting can occur as a result of nesting namespaces or types within namespaces, as a result of nesting types within classes or structs, and as a result of parameter **and local variable declarations**.

That means that if you define both `Item.description` and a local `description`. In this case the local variable hides the instance field.

> §7.6.7 When this is used in a primary-expression within an instance method or instance accessor of a class, **it is classified as a value**. The type of the value is the instance type (§10.3.1) of the class within which the usage occurs, and **the value is a reference to the object for which the method or accessor was invoked**.

That means, that `this` in C# is not a required keyword to specify instance scope. It simply is *a value* that equals the object the method is called on. That means that `this.description` is semantically equivalent to `anyItem.description` as it means accessing the `description` field on the object.

**Putting everything together:**

When `Item.description` is hidden, using `this` is the only way of accessing the hidden member. However, if it is not hidden, you can access it because it is in scope. Hence, the VS recommends to drop the `this`, because it's not needed.